# Convert string in hash sha256

Tags: hash, sha256, lazarus

I want to convert a string in a sha256 hash using DCPCrypt.
Form contains an edit to enter the string, a button to convert it and another edit to show the output sha256 hash.
I have wrote this code:

```
unit Unit1;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils, Forms, Controls, Graphics, DCPsha256, StdCtrls;

type

  { TForm1 }

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    DCP_sha256_1: TDCP_sha256;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Label1: TLabel;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { private declarations }
  public

    { public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.lfm}

{ TForm1 }

function getsha256(S: String): String;
var
    Hash: TDCP_sha256;
    Digest: array[0..31] of byte;  // sha256 produces a 256bit digest (32bytes)
    Source: string;
    i: integer;
    str1: string;
  begin
    Source:= S;  // here your string for get sha256

    if Source <> '' then
    begin
      Hash:= TDCP_sha256.Create(nil);  // create the hash
      Hash.Init;                        // initialize it
      Hash.UpdateStr(Source);
      Hash.Final(Digest);               // produce the digest
      str1:= '';
      for i:= 0 to 31 do
        str1:= str1 + IntToHex(Digest[i],2);
      //form1.Edit2.Text:= s;                   // display the digest in lower case
      Form1.Edit2.Text:=UpperCase(str1);         // display the digest in capital letter
    end;
  end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    getsha256(Edit1.Text);  // show the sha256 of string in edit1
end;
end.
```

It works. Problem is that I receive a warning and a hint from lazarus.

- Warning: Local variable "Digest" does not seems to be initialized;
- Warning: Function result does not seem to be set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first warning is a false positive. The compiler doesn't know that `Hash.Final()` will fill in the `Digest`, and you are not initializing it yourself beforehand. A simple call to [`FillByte()`](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/fillbyte.html) (or even [`FillDWord()`](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/filldword.html)) will suffice:

```pascal
FillByte(Digest, SizeOf(Digest), 0);
//FillDWord(Digest, SizeOf(Digest) div 4, 0);
```

The second warning is correct, though. Your `getsha256()` function is declared to return a `String`, but you are not setting the function's `Result` at all.  You should change this line:

```pascal
Form1.Edit2.Text:=UpperCase(str1);
```

To this instead:

```pascal
Result:=UpperCase(str1);
```

And then in `TForm1.Button1Click()`, change this line:

```pascal
getsha256(Edit1.Text);
```

To this instead:

```pascal
Edit2.Text:=getsha256(Edit1.Text);
```

Comment: Thanks for your kindness.

Comment: Is there a way to encryptt a string with a seed? To let me then decrypt that.

Comment: A hash is a 1-way value, it is not encryption. DCPCrypt has plenty of other classes for encryption/decryption.

Comment: Yes but there are no manuals to learn it.

Comment: @Wario really? It has documentation available: https://github.com/StephenGenusa/DCPCrypt/tree/master/Docs, in particular look at the pages on Ciphers and BlockCiphers. There is also an [encryption demo](https://github.com/StephenGenusa/DCPCrypt/tree/master/demos/FileEncrypt) provided.